# Operator++ from CRTP base is not visible for compiler

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, crtp

Take following piece of code as an example:

```
template<class Derived>
struct base {
    Derived operator++(int){
        auto tmp = static_cast<Derived &>(*this);
        ++static_cast<Derived &>(*this);
        return tmp;
    }
};

struct der : public base<der> {
    der &operator++(){
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    der d;
    d++;/// <<< compilation error here
}
```

I get following error from compiler:

> error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]

Why isn't my postfix operator visible for compiler? Does it contain some kind of error or is it some unknown to me C++ feature? Can this code be fixed so that postfix `operator++` will work as expected?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6727087/1639256

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two functions have the same name, `operator++`.  It's just spelled differently from a function named with an identifier.  The rule for a class member lookup is that by default, if a member with the name is found in a derived class, the base class is not checked.  The derived member "hides" the base member.

The usual way to avoid hiding a base class function with a different signature, and allow overload resolution to pick the best function, is with a using-declaration:

```
struct der : public base<der> {
    der &operator++(){
        return *this;
    }
    using base<der>::operator++;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the name `operator++` with the name `f` (that is try the same thing with an ordinary member function). You’ll have the same problem. The compiler finds the named function in `der`, so it doesn’t look in `base<dir>`. Overloading only occurs among functions defined in the same scope.